# Getting attributes via get() method vs. assigning it to a variable inside connectedCallback on web components?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering what is the best method for getting attributes for web components: using get methods or assigning them to variables inside connectedCallback. Is there any difference at all?

The following code illustrates my question:

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    get myAttribute() {
        return this.getAttribute("myAttribute");
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.myAttribute);
    }
}

customElements.define("my-component", MyComponent);
```

vs.

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {      
    connectedCallback() {
        this.myAttribute = this.getAttribute("myAttribute");
        console.log(this.myAttribute);
    }
}
    
customElements.define("my-component", MyComponent);
```